# Creating a conditional SQL select statement that inserts

Tags: php, mysql, sql, hierarchy, conditional-statements

So, I've got this table with hierchical data, and I'm trying to select the top-level and insert it into a column called 'TopLevel'

Heres what the data would look like
The top org is called Top-Level, and all lower levels have 'Top-Level' as the very top level, eventually.

```
Organization | Parent Org | GParent Org | GGParent Org | Toplevel
Top-Level | - | - | -| - |
Food Corp | Top-Level | - | -| - |
Taco Bell | Food Corp | Top-Level |  -| - |
Taco Bell Express | TacoBell | Food Corp | Top-Level | - |
KFC | Food Corp | Top-Level | -| - |
Chuck e. Cheese | Top-Level | -| - | -|
```

I can't find a close enough example that helps me understand how to do conditional selects/inserts with a string.

on the condition that Parent Org = Top-Level, Org should be selected and inserted into column top-level. In the database, if something has no more parent organizations, Top-Level appears as the parent. Wherever top-level is found, one level down(so, Food Corp, chuck e. cheese) would be selected and inserted into the column Toplevel. Hope that isn't too confusing.

Here's the semi-english version of the select statement:

```
select Org.displayName, Parent.displayName as ParentOrg_Name, GParent.displayName as gParentOrg_Name,GGParent.displayName as ggParentOrg_Name, Org.uid, Org.accountType, Org.orgType,Parent.orgType, GParent.orgType

CASE
          If Org.ParentOrg_Name == Top-Level, 
             then toplevelorg = Org.Displayname
          elseif gParentOrg_Name == Top-Level, 
              then toplevelorg = ParentOrg_Name
         elseif ggparentOrg_Name == Top-Level,
             then toplevelorg = gParentOrg_Name
           else toplevelorg = ggparentOrgName

     from dbo.Organization Org
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Organization Parent ON Org.parentOrganization_id = Parent.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Organization GParent ON Parent.parentOrganization_id = GParent.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Organization GGParent ON GParent.parentOrganization_id = GGParent.id
```

MySQL, PHP... A working TopLevel column will help me do a meaningful group-by, as I cannot simply group by parent ID without seperating the top level orgs from the lower level orgs(that they own).

Looking for teach a man to fish response, including an explaination of 'how does the select org.displayname insert into column 'toplevel' work in a statement like this? I look at these conditional statements and have trouble understanding the THEN parts'. Note that I don't know if I should put 'select toplevel' in the top select clause. I look forward to any response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL syntax for CASE is lightly different from yours, but you were close:

```
CASE
    WHEN Org.ParentOrg_Name = 'Top-Level' 
         then Org.Displayname
    WHEN gParentOrg_Name = 'Top-Level' 
         then ParentOrg_Name
    WHEN ggparentOrg_Name = 'Top-Level'
         then  gParentOrg_Name
    ELSE ggparentOrgName
END AS toplevelorg
```

Thus, the full statement would be

```
select Org.displayName,
       Parent.displayName as ParentOrg_Name,
       GParent.displayName as gParentOrg_Name,
       GGParent.displayName as ggParentOrg_Name,
       Org.uid,
       Org.accountType,
       Org.orgType,Parent.orgType,
       GParent.orgType,
       CASE
           WHEN Org.ParentOrg_Name = 'Top-Level' 
                then Org.Displayname
           WHEN gParentOrg_Name = 'Top-Level' 
                then ParentOrg_Name
           WHEN ggparentOrg_Name = 'Top-Level'
                then  gParentOrg_Name
           ELSE ggparentOrgName
       END AS toplevelorg

     from dbo.Organization Org
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Organization Parent ON Org.parentOrganization_id = Parent.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Organization GParent ON Parent.parentOrganization_id = GParent.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Organization GGParent ON GParent.parentOrganization_id = GGParent.id
```

Comment: So END AS will insert it to columnname toplevelorg? super thank you btw

Comment: and when I END AS top level org, does that require me to change the select part to have to add ", toplevelorg CASE .... END AS toplevelorg" to the end of th eselect, or just do CASE .. end as,  and that defines toplevelorg as its own column without needing to put toplevelorg twice

Comment: @J-Dizzle No, the `END` end the `CASE`, and the `AS` is the same construct that you e. g. already use in `GGParent.displayName as ggParentOrg_Name`, just with a `CASE` expression instead of a column name as the first part.

Comment: Hey, I had an error but figured it out. check out my answer for what was going on. When I got the error I thought it was the select statements 'ParentOrg_Name', but it was the use of that alias within the CASE. Again, thanks for teaching me how to fish

Comment: @J-Dizzle Maybe next time you could try to set up a test case at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ and link it in the question so answerers can check their code is valid?

Answer (score 0):

Frank PI's response mostly worked, but I got an error saying mssql_query() (php) didnt recognise the column name ParentOrg_Name and other colum names. I found that this worked, and that the aliases weren't working within the case statement. So the full statement is this:

```
select Org.displayName as Organization_Name, Parent.displayName as ParentOrg_Name,
GParent.displayName as gParentOrg_Name,GGParent.displayName as ggParentOrg_Name,
     Org.uid, Org.accountType, Org.orgType,
     CASE WHEN Parent.displayName = 'Top-Level' then Org.Displayname
         when GParent.displayName = 'Top-Level' then Parent.displayName
         when ggParent.displayName = 'Top-Level' then gParent.displayName
         else ggParent.displayName
    END AS toplevelorg
     from HQDevBox.dbo.Organization Org
     LEFT OUTER JOIN HQDevBox.dbo.Organization Parent ON Org.parentOrganization_id = Parent.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN HQDevBox.dbo.Organization GParent ON Parent.parentOrganization_id = GParent.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN HQDevBox.dbo.Organization GGParent ON GParent.parentOrganization_id = GGParent.id
```

To excercise the learning, there was another possible case where I could use CASE, because orgType returns a number, which is mapped to a string value. So here's the statement with both CASE's(is possible and works).

```
select Org.displayName as Organization_Name, Parent.displayName as ParentOrg_Name,
GParent.displayName as gParentOrg_Name,GGParent.displayName as ggParentOrg_Name,
      CASE WHEN Parent.displayName = 'Top-Level' then Org.Displayname
         when GParent.displayName = 'Top-Level' then Parent.displayName
         when ggParent.displayName = 'Top-Level' then gParent.displayName
         else ggParent.displayName
         END AS toplevelorg,
      Org.uid, Org.accountType,
      CASE WHEN Org.orgType = 0 then 'Agency'
           when Org.orgType = 1 then 'Essential'
           when Org.orgType = 2 then 'Power'
           when Org.orgType = 3 then 'Sub_Agency'
           when Org.orgType = 4 then 'Sub_Organization'
           END AS orgType
     from HQDevBox.dbo.Organization Org
     LEFT OUTER JOIN HQDevBox.dbo.Organization Parent ON Org.parentOrganization_id = Parent.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN HQDevBox.dbo.Organization GParent ON Parent.parentOrganization_id = GParent.id
     LEFT OUTER JOIN HQDevBox.dbo.Organization GGParent ON GParent.parentOrganization_id = GGParent.id
```

Hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: Just as a note: There is a short form for `CASE` useful for your other case: You could say `CASE Org.orgType WHEN 0 THEN 'Agency' WHEN 1 THEN 'Essential' ... END`.